# libicuuc.so.52, needed libboost_regex-mt.so

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, icu

## Introduction

I want to a compile a code that uses ICU and libboost. For this purpose I am using the following `install.sh` file. The problem is that I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.52, needed by /opt/boost-1.54.0/lib/libboost_regex.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

**I know** that I have to add something in the **cmakeLists.txt** file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -rpath=/opt/icu_52.1/")
```

But It's not working:

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath=/opt/icu_52.1/’
```

**When I try:** `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=/opt/icu_52.1/")`

**error:** `/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.52, needed by /opt/boost-1.54.0/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`

---

## Install.sh

```
module load icu-52.1
module load boost_1_54_0
module load qt5.5.0

ENTLK_DIST=/home/hani/ENTLK_DIST

export BOOST_ROOT=/opt/boost-1.54.0/
export ICU_ROOT=/opt/icu_52.1/

export PATH=/opt/qt-5.5.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/qt-5.5.0/lib


#######################################
# compile and install in ENTLK_DIST
#######################################
export ENTLK_DIST=/home/hani/ENTLK_DIST

mkdir -p build && cd build
rm -f CMakeCache.txt
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ENTLK_DIST 
make -j8 && make install
```

---

## CmakeLists.txt

```
project(Entlk)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Support C++11
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG(-std=c++11 HAVE_STDCPP11)
if (HAVE_STDCPP11)
  message("-- C++11 supported")
  add_definitions(-DHAVE_STDCPP11) # to be used in the cpp code
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lboost_regex")
else (HAVE_STDCPP11)
  message("-- C++11 NOT supported")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DNO_STDCPP11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif (HAVE_STDCPP11)

# warnings
# disable warnings on unknown pragmas (used by sqlite_modern)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-W -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

#use Stanford NER instead of MITIE
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DUSE_STANFORD_NER ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

# display install directory
message(STATUS "Install directory is CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configure third party librairies
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
include(cmake/EntlkUtils.cmake)

# Path to look for FindXXX.cmake files
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" # available in this project
)

find_package(ICU 4.4 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${ICU_INCLUDE_DIRS})


# include Qt (for lima)
include(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/manageQt5.cmake)
addQt5Modules(Core Xml)
include_directories(${Qt5_INCLUDES})
set(QT_LIBRARIES "${Qt5_LIBRARIES}")


find_package(Boost 1.46 REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex serialization system filesystem program_options timer log)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
# add define needed by Boost Log
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
#message(STATUS "using Boost libraries ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

Comment: @Antonio I am sure that I have to add something there. But I forgot the right command

Comment: Try with: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=/opt/icu_52.1/")` (Note the additional `-Wl,`) Anyways, in cmake you do that exactly by adding directories using the command `link_directories`: it seems that the `libicuuc.so.52 is not in your `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS` path.

Comment: First of all, find if you have `libicuuc.so.52`, and where it is located

Comment: oh it's in /opt/icu_52.1/lib. I therefore I have to add /opt/icu_52.1/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
link_directories(/opt/icu_52.1/lib)
```

You can also try to see if somebody has written a find package for ICU, anyway it's not among the standard cmake modules.

Comment: @Antonios is the same as  -Wl,-rpath=/opt/icu_52.1/"  ?

Comment: @HaniGoc It's better, you leave the work of adding the right flags to cmake. You shouldn't mix `rpath` flags with cmake commands.